# How can I set up an alias for a command?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to set up a shorter name as an alias of this command:

```
sudo -i pantheon-files $(pwd)
```

For example I want to type `sfoh` (for sudo file open here) and it should run this command.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### For this session

Simply run this command:

```
alias key='your long command'
```

### Permanently

Add the commands as described above into `.bash_aliases`.

Open scratch with the Applications menu and edit the file `.bash_aliases` in your home directory. It's a hidden file, so press Ctrl+H to see it.

Or you can type in the terminal: `scratch-text-editor ~/.bash_aliases`

Then add into it the following line:

```
alias key='your long command'
```

To apply the changes immediately run this command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to allow for passing in an option.

Comment: @Tim yes key is the short command

Comment: @LewisGoddard Don't know what you mean but for his case it works.

Comment: for those who use zsh, you can add the alias at ~/.zshrc

Comment: @Djax I meant the line `alias key=...` doesn't take options, like the directory in this example, unless it does and I'm just being silly.

Comment: @LewisGoddard it does :) It just replaces the alias key with the full cmd and then execute it in the bash.

Answer (score 4):

Creating an alias is quite simple, and it opens a whole realm of possibility for adding shortcuts to your terminal usage.

### In General:

Open up `~/.bashrc` in your favourite text editor, and add the following to the end:

```
alias <string>='<full and long command>'
```

### For your specific example:

Again, adding to the end of the `.bashrc` file:

```
alias sfoh='sudo -i pantheon-files $(pwd)'
```

This does not require a restart to take effect, but it will require a new terminal window to be opened so that the `~/.bashrc` file can be parsed again.

Comment: @Tim Technically anywhere is okay, so long as bash loads it, but `~/.bash_aliases` is the default I believe.

Comment: @Tim I'm of the belief that the fewer configuration files I have, the better, so I use `.bashrc`. I've never tried `.bashrc_aliases`, so YMMV