# Why can I not use Scratch text editor to create files from the Terminal?

Tags: code

Let's say I want to create a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` and I do something like

```
sudo -i gedit /usr/share/applications/cipricus.desktop
```

This will open that file in gedit.

If I try to use the default text editor Scratch,

```
sudo -i scratch-text-editor /usr/share/applications/cipricus.desktop
```

that will just open Scratch.

If that file already exists, Scratch will open it just like Gedit does. But it doesn't seem able to create files. I have also tried without the need of administrator privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, if you do open scratch text editor in the debug mode using

`scratch-text-editor test.py -d`

if the file does not exists, you will see someting like this in the terminal

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 11:26:52.180479] Scratch.vala:236: Error when getting
information for file '/hello': No such file or directory
```

Which means that the file/folder does not exists.

I think you should report this on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/scratch)

Ps: you can have the list of possible options in terminal using `scratch-text-editor --help-all`

Comment: I will just use Gedit as I used to anyway. I was just curious. Scratch has a too long a name anyway to use it in Terminal :)

Comment: @cipricus you can create a command alias , for more informations : http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/alias

Comment: @Bilal You should post links to english sites. And if already answerd in this SE better to link it here.
http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-can-i-set-up-an-alias-for-a-command

Comment: @Djax I will do in the futur

Comment: @BilalElmoussaoui I reported this issue on July the 3rd: https://bugs.launchpad.net/scratch/+bug/1471053 Please mark yourself as affected over there.

Answer (score 5):

You can set up an alias to create the file if it doesn't exist. First, create the bash file:

```
touch .bash_aliases
scratch-text-editor .bash_aliases
```

Then add the following:

```
scratch() {
    touch $1
    scratch-text-editor $1
}
```

This will set the command `scratch` to make the file (with `touch`) and then edit it with `scratch-text-editor`. `$1` means the first argument given.

This solves the other issue of the command for scratch being annoyingly long. Anyway, restart your terminal, and check the top. If you see an error like this:

```
bash: /home/tim/.bash_aliases: line 2: unexpected EOF...
```

or any error about the file, then check you've entered it all correctly.