# How to easily start playing an Audio CD - with CDDB/freeDB support?

Tags: audio, audio-cd, audio-player

How to easily access a music CD after having inserted it?

Is automatic play-when-inserted possible?

I just want to insert the CD and then with a click or two start playing in a music player that would hopefully also fetch the proper names (CDDB, freeDB).

Comment: comment to give a reason for your down-vote and help me fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Audacious** can start playing an audio CD by going to *Services, Play CD*, and it has good CDDB support.

`sudo apt-get install audacious`

The command `audacious` will just start the application, but `audacious cdda://` will start playing the Audio CD in Audacious.

So, that can be run with a short-key or by creating an Audacious desktop file in `usr/share/applications` with the above command and then make that executable so that it will be found with the Super-Space launcher.

To easily do that in terminal we need a text editor like Gedit, Leafpad or Mousepad ([Scratch is not usable in the same way](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/328/170).) The example here is with Gedit.

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/audacious_cd.desktop
```

There, paste this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=AudioVideo;Player;Audio;Qt;
Exec=audacious cdda://
Icon=audacious
Name=Play Audio CD with Audacious
Type=Application
```

Then, save, close and do

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/audacious_cd.desktop
```

Now, in Applications launcher, when typing 'CD', you should see "Play Audio CD with Audacious".

Also, if prefered, a such desktop file can be dragged&dropped onto the dock too.

---

The same is possible for **Qmmp**.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:forkotov02/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qmmp qmmp-plugin-pack
```

Then add the following command to a short-key (or to a desktop file as above):

`qmmp cdda://`

---

**Deadbeef** will play a CD with the option *File-Add audio CD*, which adds the CD tracks to a playlist. -- Or with the command

`deadbeef all.cda`

which then can be used as specified in the other cases above.

**Deadbeef** had a bug that prevented it from fetching CDDB metadata.

To fix that be sure that "Prefer CD-Text over CDDB" under Preferences-Plugins-Audio CD player-Configure is NOT checked. Details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257717/32012).